# How to convert list to dictionary with default value using underscore functions?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to convert list to dictionary with default value using underscore.js functions ?
Can I code below zip to less lines with underscore ?

```
l = [1, 2, 3];
d = {};
for (var i in l){
  d[l[i]] = 'defaut value';
}
```

Comment: [1,2,3].map(function(a){ this[a]='default'}, d={});

Comment: @dandavis: Why `map`? Why `this` instead of simply `d`?

Comment: using this runs faster than closuring d and avoids hard-coding the logic to the data. forEach would works as well, even slightly faster, i'm just in the habit of using map() so that i can log the iterations using return while i build. i convert 'hot loops' to forEach once it's tested or some/every if i can get away with bailing early...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like this:

```
var l = [1, 2, 3];
var d = _.object(_.map(l, function(x) { return [x, 'default value']; }));
```

Or this:

```
var l = [1, 2, 3];
var d = _.reduce(l, function(m, x) { m[x] = 'default value'; return m; }, {});
```

Comment: Also correct: var d = _(l).reduce(function(m, x) { m[x] = 'default value'; return m; }, {});

Comment: You could also use `_.chain` with the first one, `_(l).chain().map(...).object().value()`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZEg2m/